# Can XSS and phising type attacks jump across browsers?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

If I had two different browsers and separated their use such that I was only ever using browser A for things such as on-line banking and credit card purchases etc. And used browser B for everything else, then if browser B got had malicious scripts installed would my browser activities on browser A be safe?

Comment: Did you read about the recent Tumblr worm?

Comment: What type of "malicious *installed* scripts" do you mean? If you install something which gets file system access, it's your fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since malicious client side scripts have no direct access to the underlying filesystem or OS of the client, they can not be transmitted across browsers.

However, if you have malicious bookmarks or addons installed and *voluntarily* transfer them, perhaps in ignorance, then the other browser is also vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

Depends if "malicious scripts installed" are at an OS level, or at a browser level. If something infects your OS, any application is vulnerable.